# How to invoke(not call directly) the Task<T>'s ContinueWith method?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

For some business reasons, I cannot call the service's method directly, so I wrote the code like this:

```
class TheService {
    public Task<string> CallMe(string input) {
        return Task.Run(() => {
            return "the result of " + input;
        });
    }
}

//The calling code segment...

//Get the target method's info
MethodInfo mi = typeof(TheService).GetMethod("CallMe");

//Get the target method's return type, yes, it's a Task<string>
ParameterInfo pi = mi.ReturnParameter;
Type taskType = pi.ParameterType;

//Get the service instance.(I new it here for simple reason)
TheService svc = new TheService();

//Invoke the target method and get the Task<string>, however I got only an object (not Task<string>) because I invoke it, not call it directly
object task = mi.Invoke(svc, new[] {"test"});

//How can I make a ContinueWith call here?

//This isn't work! It throws a conversion exception.
//Note: Task<string> is just an example. I wound actually get Task<MyClassA> or Task<MyClassB> here. So, I cannot hard code the conversion. However, I know the Type of Task<T> here. My instinct tells me I should use Invoke again but I don't know how to do.
((Task<object>)task).ContinueWith(a=>{
    Console.WriteLine("The result is " + a.Result);
});
```

My question is how to call the object's (It's actually a Task) ContinueWith method?

Or anything workaround?

Comment: What did the conversion exception actually say?

Comment: He does not know statically what the type argument is going to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the base class `Task`:

```
((Task)task).ContinueWith(a=>{
    Console.WriteLine("The result is " + ((dynamic)a).Result);
});
```

Inside the completion callback `((dynamic)a).Result` will be of type `dynamic` here. You can cast it or interrogate it using reflection. You can use reflection in the first place instead of `dynamic` if you like that better.

Another idea:

```
static void Run<T>(Task<T> task) {
 ...
}

Run((dynamic)task);
```

This uses `dynamic` to match the generic type arguments so that the call works.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you cast `Task<string>` to `Task<object>`.

```
((Task<string>)task).ContinueWith(a => {
    Console.WriteLine("The result is " + a.Result);
});
```

Remember that types with different generic constraint are not interchangeable.

If situation is trick that the task return type is unknown, you can keep using reflection.

```
((Task)task).ContinueWith(t =>
{
    var resultProperty = t.GetType().GetProperty("Result");
    var resultObject = resultProperty.GetValue(t);
    Console.WriteLine("The result is " + resultObject);
});
```

Comment: "Remember that types with different generic constraint are not interchangeable" Not strictly true for covariant type parameters declared with the [`out` keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx) in interfaces, but for the purposes of this question, good enough.

Comment: @spender out keyword worths mentioning. Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I didn't describe the question clearly. Task<string> is just an example. I wound actually get Task<MyClassA> or Task<MyClassB> here. I have edited the question.